# How to add page "Contact us"/"Terms of usage" using a link in the footer but page's content to be in the main content(middle region)?

Tags: navigation

This seems to be a very newbie question. This is what I want to do:

I 'd like to have a link of type "Terms of usage"/"contact us" in the footer, and when the user clicks on it, a page to be appeared in the main region. 
How that could be done? Is it possible? Because from what I 've already seen, the page appears in the same theme region with its parent menu.

Comment: What version of Drupal are you using? What other modules or customizations may be affecting the menu system or the rendering of content on pages? When clicking on a menu link, the page's content should always be displaying in the Content region in D6 and in whatever region you have placed the "System Main" block in D7. There should be no relationship between where the menu is placed and where the page's content is rendered unless you have added some configuration to create that functionality.

Answer (score 1):

Do not know the version your using., search for 'overlay' in modules there are many.

In Drupal 7. Grab the following for direction

http://drupal.org/project/admin_path

http://drupal.org/project/context_overlay

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment yet so I'm posting this as an answer. Seems like what you are asking for is default Drupal behaviour. If you create a new 'Basic page' called Terms of Usage, and link to that page, it will appear in the main region.

Can you clarify what you meant by 'the page appears in the same theme region with its parent menu'? Providing a link would also be helpful.

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately I don't have a link because I have it only local. Ok if i create a new Basic page and link the page with a menu, that page will appeared in the same region where the menu is. But I want for example(!) the link "Terms of Usage" to be in the footer, and when I click it, the text/content of the terms to be appeared not in the footer but in the header (for example)

Answer (score 0):

You could try using Ajax/jQuery to make your T&C/Contact form.
Here is a [good tutorial](http://www.elated.com/articles/slick-ajax-contact-form-jquery-php/)